# Updating MySQL database with PHP, sets all columns to 0 instead of 1

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database I'm updating, and when I change one symptom, I want it to reset all of the values in the symptom severity row to 0, but when I update that one symptom, its setting ALL of the rows to 0, instead of just that row. Here's my code, I did it in if statements. If you know of an easier way, it'd be greatly appreciated as well.

I am not using a WHERE  because I want all id's to be changed, not just one, and it's generating them on the fly. I have 20 symptoms which are updated in ID 1 only in the database. Sorry if the code sucks, I'm pretty new at this.

If I update all 20 at once, great, but if I only update one or two, they all get set back to 0.

```
mysql_select_db("$database", $conn) or die(mysql_error());

// if statements to delete this and that

$db="$id"."_symp";

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $db";

$getit = mysql_query ( $sql2, $conn );

// I know I'm using outdated SQL, but it works for me, so I keep using it
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getit, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        //symptom 1
        if ($_POST[symptom1] == $row[symptom1]) {
            print " ";
        }
        else {
            mysql_query("UPDATE $db SET symptom1_sev = '0'") OR die(mysql_error()); 
        }

        //symptom 2
        if ($_POST[symptom2] == $row[symptom2]) {
            print " ";
        }
        else {
            mysql_query("UPDATE $db SET symptom2_sev = '0'") OR die(mysql_error()); 
        }

        //symptom 3
        if ($_POST[symptom3] == $row[symptom3]) {
            print " ";
        }
        else {
            mysql_query("UPDATE $db SET symptom3_sev = '0'") OR die(mysql_error()); 
        }
        //and so on to 20

        //symptom 20
        if ($_POST[symptom20] == $row[symptom20]) {
            print " ";
        }
        else {
            mysql_query("UPDATE $db SET symptom20_sev = '0'") OR die(mysql_error()); 
        }

        //end sql stuff
    }

// update the database
$sql="UPDATE $db SET 
        symptom1='$_POST[symptom1]', symptom2='$_POST[symptom2]', symptom3='$_POST[symptom3]',       symptom4='$_POST[symptom4]', symptom5='$_POST[symptom5]', symptom6='$_POST[symptom6]', symptom7='$_POST[symptom7]', symptom8='$_POST[symptom8]', symptom9='$_POST[symptom9]', symptom10='$_POST[symptom10]', symptom11='$_POST[symptom11]', symptom12='$_POST[symptom12]', symptom13='$_POST[symptom13]', symptom14='$_POST[symptom14]', symptom15='$_POST[symptom15]', symptom16='$_POST[symptom16]', symptom17='$_POST[symptom17]', symptom18='$_POST[symptom18]', symptom19='$_POST[symptom19]', symptom20='$_POST[symptom20]' 
    WHERE id=1" OR die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db('$database');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
    {
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
echo "Updated data successfully\n";

mysql_close($conn);
```

Thanks a bunch. Sorry I'm such a n00b. Or a nob, whichever you prefer to call me!

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Your `UPDATE` needs a `WHERE` clause.  (To limit which rows are operated on)  see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: If this is a new application you really shouldn't be using the massively obsolete `mysql_query` interface.

Comment: Unless every single $_POST is equal to every single corresponding $row, your conditionals are all returning false.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Each conditional just tests one column in the current row against the corresponding `$_POST` parameter. Some will be true, some will be false.

Comment: Thanks. I don't use WHERE because I'm updating dynamic ID's, as on another form they're adding to the database by submitting how severe each symptom is, ebyrob. To tadman, I plan on changing it when I get a bit better. Thank you guys. I am such a knob today!! (You don't need to call me names, can if you want, I KNOW I'm an inexperienced knob, but I've always gotten good answers here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update all the symptoms in one step with the following query:

```
$symptom1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['symptom1']);
$symptom2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['symptom2']);
...
$symptom20 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['symptom20']);

$sql = "
    UPDATE $db
    SET symptom1_sev = IF(symptom1 = '$symptom1', 0, symptom1_sev),
        symptom2_sev = IF(symptom2 = '$symptom2', 0, symptom2_sev),
        ...
        symptom20_sev = IF(symptom20 = '$symptom20', 0, symptom20_sev)";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This will stop the setting of every symptom*_sev to 0 as well? Sorry. I'm learning! I guess the more I screw up, the more I learn!!

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I'm using the above code, no errors. So far so good.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a database I'm updating, and when I change one symptom, 
>   I want it to reset all of the values in the symptom severity row to 0, 
>   but when I update that one symptom, its setting ALL of the rows to 0,
>   instead of just that row.

Your code calls `UPDATE` with no `WHERE` clause.  `UPDATE` without `WHERE` will always update every single **row** in the entire table every time.

> I am not using a WHERE because I want all id's to be changed, 
>   not just one, and it's generating them on the fly. 
>   I have 20 symptoms which are updated in ID 1 only in the database. 
>   Sorry if the code sucks, I'm pretty new at this.

So you want to update 20 **columns** in one **row**?  Fine.  You still need a `WHERE` clause, just put in a bunch more columns in the `UPDATE` statement.  (Or consider making your DB schema more useful)

PS - If this still sounds wrong, consider sharing your DB schema (table names and column names/types for pertinent tables) with us.

Every one of these queries is wrong and will change every single row:

```
    //symptom 1
    if ($_POST[symptom1] == $row[symptom1]) {
        print " ";
    }
    else {
        mysql_query("UPDATE $db SET symptom1_sev = '0'") OR die(mysql_error()); 
    }
```

Finally, if clearing severity in other rows *is* what you want, then you never ever actually set severity anywhere, even for current row.  (So why wouldn't it always be 0?)

e.g. `SET symptom1_sev = '$_POST[symptom1]'` just never happens.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Sorry, I always mix up rows and columns, always have. What I want to do, if symptom 1 is changed, I want to clear out all of symptom1_sev's entries, set them back to 0 because its a different symptom. However, if symptom 2 hasn't changed, I don't want any of symptom2_sev's to change, because there are entries that need to be kept. 
However, I want to set ALL of the id entries for symptom1_sev to 0, and I'd need to do that with a wildcard, as on another form, you're adding to symptom1_sev every time you use the form.
Does that make sense? And thank you.

Comment: Sorry I'm such a knob, I was just playing around. I'm pretty new at this, and I find a lot of good answers here. I thought I had it. I'm just experimenting, I'm self taught with a bit of basics from SQL server in college.. 4 years ago.. I've got an education as a computer engineer, I'm not much of a coder. If the above info doesn't help, I'll post more about the DB, and I am willing to change the hell out of it. Thanks. (The users enter and can edit the symptoms, and on another form, they can add how severe they are for a chart)

Comment: @user3058860 aha! the severity is on different page.  that explains it.  Sorry if I was terse, I'm just trying to figure out what the various rows and columns and tables represent.  Without knowing that, it's very hard to give you useful advice.  Is a row sort of "per disease"?  Is there only ever 1 row in the table?  Is a row "per patient"?  Just what would change that would move us from one row in the symptom table to another row?  (and had you thought about using relationship to allow multiple symptoms to be represented with different rows instead of different hard-numbered columns)?